# Finding all records after a specific row from each group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to find out all the records from each group those appear after a specific row  i.e

source table :

[image]

Now my requirement is to  find all items from each group after **orange**

expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where true
qualify countif(item='orange') over(partition by category order by ts) > if(item = 'orange', 1, 0)
```

note: you must have some column that define order of purchases - like for example timestamp, date, etc. In above example it is `ts` field

If apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks !! It really helped me and I also have a timestamp field . I was thinking of one scenario if 'Orange' as in above example is not present in one of the groups, then in that case I want all the records from that group. May be I need to append one more condition like qualify (countif(item='orange') over(partition by category order by purchases ) > if(item = 'orange', 1, 0) or (countif(item='orange') over(partition by category ) = 0)) in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use cumulative `max`:

```
with mytable as (
  select 'Veg-1' as category, 'kale' as item, 20 as purchases union all
  select 'Veg-1', 'orange', 30 union all
  select 'Veg-1', 'apple', 40 union all
  select 'Veg-2', 'orange', 20 union all
  select 'Veg-2', 'kale', 30 union all
  select 'Veg-2', 'apple', 40
)
select *
from mytable
where true
qualify max(item='orange') over (partition by category order by purchases) = true
  and item != 'orange'
```

[image]